# python graph not showing up

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

So I tried graphing a data frame using pandas and when I typed it out there is a blank image that shows up with no errors or anything. I was hoping someone knows what the problem could be and how I can solve it.

[image: This is the code that I used]

[image: This is the blank image I get]

I was wondering if this is a backend issue or what. Thank you!

Comment: Please copy your code directly into the question instead of adding an image of it

Comment: Are you sure that the points you are adding to the scatter plots exist? i.e. Are `df_top10[df_top10['Country Name'] ==k]['year'] and ['life ladder']` are non empty?

Comment: sorry I am new to this will note that for next time. I did create a new variable combining two data sets together.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Plotly's Jupyter notebooks documentation](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#jupyter-notebook-support)? There's instructions on how to configure your Jupyter notebook to display Plotly figures

Answer (score 0):

For faster answers, we need the code in text format and sample data for reproduction. I have tried to apply the sample from the official reference to your code. The reason why the graph doesn't show up is a guess, since I don't have any code or data, but I think the country name is not retrieved from the dictionary. I extracted the top 10 countries from the sample data by population, and drew a graph based on the data extracted from the original data frame for those country names. The data used as the basis for the looping process is a dictionary of country names and arbitrary colors.

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
df1 = px.data.gapminder().query('year==2007').sort_values('pop', ascending=False).head(10)
```

**df1**

|  | country | continent | year | lifeExp | pop | gdpPercap | iso_alpha | iso_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 299 | China | Asia | 2007 | 72.961 | 1318683096 | 4959.11 | CHN | 156 |
| 707 | India | Asia | 2007 | 64.698 | 1110396331 | 2452.21 | IND | 356 |
| 1619 | United States | Americas | 2007 | 78.242 | 301139947 | 42951.7 | USA | 840 |
| 719 | Indonesia | Asia | 2007 | 70.65 | 223547000 | 3540.65 | IDN | 360 |
| 179 | Brazil | Americas | 2007 | 72.39 | 190010647 | 9065.8 | BRA | 76 |
| 1175 | Pakistan | Asia | 2007 | 65.483 | 169270617 | 2605.95 | PAK | 586 |
| 107 | Bangladesh | Asia | 2007 | 64.062 | 150448339 | 1391.25 | BGD | 50 |
| 1139 | Nigeria | Africa | 2007 | 46.859 | 135031164 | 2013.98 | NGA | 566 |
| 803 | Japan | Asia | 2007 | 82.603 | 127467972 | 31656.1 | JPN | 392 |
| 995 | Mexico | Americas | 2007 | 76.195 | 108700891 | 11977.6 | MEX | 484 |

```
# create dict country and color

colors = px.colors.sequential.Plasma
color = {k:v for k,v in zip(df1.country,colors)}

{'China': '#0d0887',
 'India': '#46039f',
 'United States': '#7201a8',
 'Indonesia': '#9c179e',
 'Brazil': '#bd3786',
 'Pakistan': '#d8576b',
 'Bangladesh': '#ed7953',
 'Nigeria': '#fb9f3a',
 'Japan': '#fdca26',
 'Mexico': '#f0f921'}

# top10 data
df1_top10 = px.data.gapminder().query('country in @df1.country')

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
colors = px.colors.sequential.Plasma

for k,v in color.items():
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df1_top10[df1_top10['country']==k]['year'],
        y=df1_top10[df1_top10['country']==k]['lifeExp'],
        name=k,
        mode='markers+text+lines',
        marker_color='black',
        marker_size=3,
        line=dict(color=color[k]),
        yaxis='y1'))
    
fig.update_layout(
    title="Top 10 Country wise Life Ladder trend",
    xaxis_title="Year",
    yaxis_title="Life Ladder",
    template='ggplot2',
    font=dict( size=16, 
              color="Black", 
              family="Garamond"
             ),
    xaxis=dict(showgrid=True),
    yaxis=dict(showgrid=True)
) 
fig.show()
```

[image]